# WPF property grid - Disable individual properties

Tags: wpf, propertygrid

I'm trying to use the property grid.

I'm creating a dynamic object of all the properties in my property grid and using that to bind to a view.

I realise the property grid has a ReadOnly and a Browsable attribute.

However, I want to disable the setting. Say a radio button. How can I do this?

Also, if I want to define dependencies between my properties, how do I do it dynamically?

Comment: Can you show us some example what you exactly want? Maybe some code will be helpful.